# Count the columns value accordingly to the value in a specific row in a python matrix

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

```
mat = [ [1,3,5,7], [1,2,5,7], [8,2,3,4] ]
```

I have to design a function that can count the number of rows with the same value (per column) taking into account a reference row.

The result array for every row will be

```
row0 = [2,1,2,2]
row1 = [2,2,2,2]
row3 = [1,2,1,1]
```

every row of the matrix mat is a user and every columns is a tag for the user's position in a defined unit of time. So I have to count for every defined time (i.e. the columns)how many users share the same position.

I try to use the numpy count_nonzero function but it requires a condition that I cannot be able to spread across all the reference row

Comment: Could there be duplicates within the same row in the input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `numpy` solution using `argsort. This can handle non-integer entries:

```
import numpy as np

def count_per_col(a):
    o = np.argsort(a, 0)
    ao = np.take_along_axis(a, o, 0)
    padded = np.ones((ao.shape[1], ao.shape[0]+1), int)
    padded[:, 1:-1] = np.diff(ao, axis=0).T
    i, j = np.where(padded)
    j = np.maximum(np.diff(j), 0)
    J = j.repeat(j)
    out = np.empty(a.shape, int)
    np.put_along_axis(out, o, J.reshape(out.shape[::-1]).T, 0)
    return out

mat = np.array([[1,3,5,7], [1,2,5,7], [8,2,3,4]])

count_per_col(mat)
# array([[2, 1, 2, 2],
#        [2, 2, 2, 2],
#        [1, 2, 1, 1]])
```

How fast?

```
from timeit import timeit

large = np.random.randint(0, 100, (100, 10000))
large = np.random.random(100)[large]

timeit(lambda: count_per_col(large), number=10)/10
# 0.1332556433044374
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple, vectorized solution is to use

```
mat = np.array([
    [1,3,5,7],
    [1,2,5,7],
    [8,2,3,4]
])

tmp = mat + np.arange(mat.shape[1]) * np.max(mat)
np.bincount(tmp.ravel())[tmp]
# array([[2, 1, 2, 2],
#        [2, 2, 2, 2],
#        [1, 2, 1, 1]])
```

Timings for a 64x8640 matrix:

```
# 4 ms ± 300 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution that is 1) count the number of elements you have in each column, 2) use that count to build another list.

```py
from collections import Counter

mat = [[1,3,5,7], [1,2,5,7], [8,2,3,4]]
col_counts = [Counter(col) for col in zip(*mat)]
results = [[count[cell] for cell, count in zip(row, col_counts)] for row in mat]
```

The result is:

```
[[2, 1, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2], [1, 2, 1, 1]]
```

Note that in the first row `[1,3,5,7]`, element `3` corresponds to a `1` not a zero as you have exactly one `3` in the second column `[3, 2, 2]`.

A slightly lighter solution (only uses one counter at a time), I also detailed the transformation line by line so it's easier to understand:

```py
def row_count(mat):
    def row_transform(row):
        count = Counter(row)
        return [count[e] for e in row]

    matT = zip(*mat)
    matT_count = map(row_transform, matT)
    return zip(*matT_count)
```

If you need a list then you can call `list(row_count(mat))` if you only need to iterate over your rows you can do `for row in row_count(mat):` and it will save you some more memory (only instantiating one row at a time).

Comment: Thank you so much.